# pre populate database field after registration in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSuserbundle and I'm trying to pre populate a field in my database on registration. 
I'm trying to auto add values like "http://localhost:1337/digitalartlab/web/profile/{username}/checkin". Username would be the only variable of this string. How can I do this?

User.php

```
   /**
     * Set checkinurl
     *
     * @param string $checkinurl
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCheckinurl($checkinurl)
    {
        $this->checkinurl = $checkinurl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkinurl
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCheckinurl()
    {
        return $this->checkinurl;
    }
```

registrationtype.php (Some extra fields I added to the registration form).

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace DigitalArtLabBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname');
        $builder->add('lastname');
        $builder->add('address');
        $builder->add('zipcode');
        $builder->add('Expertises');
        $builder->add('Interesses');
        $builder->add('saldo', 'integer', array(
            'label' => 'Saldo',
            'data' => '0'
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

registrationcontroller: (the disabled codes are my own attempts to populate the field)

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

    $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
    if ($process) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        $authUser = false;
        if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
        } else {
            $authUser = true;
            /*$userdata = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user->getUsername());
            $namespace = 'localhost:1337/digitalartlab/web/profile';
            $userdata->setCheckinurl('http://'.$namespace.'/'.$user->getUsername().'/checkin');*/
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
        }

        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        if ($authUser) {
            $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
        }



        return $response;
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I've read the documentation but it's all just really confusing to me. I hope someone can help me make it clear how this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a registration listener to perform this task.  See the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html).

Be sure to add a service for the listener in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    your_bundle.registration_listener:
        class: YourBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Listener:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * RegistrationListener 
 *
 */
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
       $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
       $userName = $user->getUserName();
       $checkInUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/digitalartlab/web/profile/' . $username;
       $user->setCheckinurl($checkInUrl);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have removed an unnecessary reference to the Doctrine Entity Manger.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot!